# Create a session after login authentication php

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have created a login page using ajax and php but I want to create a session for each user who has logged in how can I achieve this?

This is my ajax

```
// this is the id of the form
$("#login-form-data").submit(function(e) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/connection.php",
        data: {
            form_data : $("#login-form-data").serialize()
        }, // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data); // show response from the php script.
            if(data == 'Login Successful'){
                window.location = 'home-page.php';
            }

        }
    });

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

This is my php authencation

```
if(isset($form_data)){

    $credentials = getCleanOutput($form_data);
    echo authenticateUser($credentials[0],$credentials[1]);

}

function authenticateUser($_username,$_password){

    $hostname='localhost';
    $username='root';
    $password='1111';
    $allRows = [];

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=auction_software",$username,$password);
    $sql = "select password,salt from ilance_users where username ='".$_username."'";
    $a = $dbh->query($sql);
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {

        $allRowClean = [];
        foreach($row as $value => $rowData){

            if(!is_numeric($value)){
                $allRowClean[$value] = $rowData;
            }

        }
        array_push($allRows,$allRowClean);

    }

    if(count($allRows) == 0){
        return "User not found";
    }
    else if(count($allRows) > 1){
        return "Multiple Users found!";
    }else{

        $hashed = md5(md5($_password).$allRows[0]['salt']);
        if($hashed == $allRows[0]['password']){
            return 'Login Successful';
        }else{
            return 'Incorrect Password!';
        }
    }

}
```

If the password has matched with the hash in the database I send Login successful back to ajax , where I check that and redirect the user to the home page. How can I pass the user name and store in a session in the home page?

Comment: is that a part of your php script? what is the `$form_data` , does there any errors? what actually happens there? and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: form-data contains the serialised data of the form. No errors. I just need to know how to create session

Comment: [session in php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add php session in your code :

```
session_start();
if($hashed == $allRows[0]['password']){

    $_SESSION["login"] = true;
    $_SESSION["username"] = $_username;
    return true;
}else{
    $_SESSION["login"] = false;
    return 'Incorrect Password!';
}
```

And check the session in your home-page.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION["login"]!=true){
    //Link to login page
}else{
    echo $_SESSION["username"];
}
?>
```

Hope it resolve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
```

And After:

```
if ($hashed == $allRows[0]['password']) {
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
    return 'Login Successful';
}
```

In Html file:

```
<h1>Welcome <?= $_SESSION['login_user'] ?></h1>
```

Logout :

```
if(session_destroy()) {
  header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select the password of the user in your select statement also select the id for example:

```
$sql = "select id,password,salt from ilance_users where username ='".$_username."'";
```

Then before you return "Login Successful" above this declare the session such as:

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
return 'Login Successful';
```

Next at the top of home-page.php you need to start the session:

```
session_start();
```